# Sony Vaio Pro 13 can't boot after install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, sony

I am stuck with this screen "**Your VAIO failed to start Windows**" after installing Ubuntu 14.04 by using the whole disk. Please guide me to fix this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this is Secure Boot.

You can disable Secure Boot on your system following these [instructions](http://docs.esupport.sony.com/pc/SVT1112_1312_1411_series/EN/contents/07/02/08/08.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. Unfortunately I still have same problem after disable Secure Boot as your link. :(

Comment: What options do you have on your BIOS settings?